# Help with glueviz install

Tags: python

I'm kinda struggling with this glue install. For some reason ubuntu 17.10 has generally been a pain for me, so I'm not sure if this is connected to other problems with the version or not.

I'm trying to install Glueviz. I normally install using Anaconda, but was getting this issue and couldn't fix it. Basically I'll install Glueviz using either apt or anaconda, and when I try to startup glue, I get a "no module named 'setuptools'"

I tried installing setup tools several ways.

I tried installing using apt-get install python-setuptools, and I tried downloading the setuptools package zip file and installing from there, but it still doesn't get rid of this error message.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get glue working again?